# `babel` - Getting the language loaded?

Tags: babel, options

How can I get the value of the language used by babel?

I know that I can use `\@ifpackagewith{babel}{french}{<true>}{<false>}` but this command makes my code very ugly with several nested blocks like in the following pseudo-code.

```
% French
\iflanguage{french}{
    ...
% English
}{
    \iflanguage{english}{
        ...
% Unsupported
    }{
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to use a `switch` block instead of nested `if` blocks.

Comment: What about `\iflanguage{french}{true}{false}`? Section 1.19 in the manual of `babel`.

Comment: What about `\makeatletter Loaded languages: \bbl@loaded` ?

Comment: Can you please specify your question? In the title you ask about the *loaded* language, while in the text you mention the *used* one. `babel` can load multiple languages but uses obviously only one (well, more or less).

Comment: @egreg Yes it is simpler but my problem is still there.

Comment: @projetmbc You didn't explain what's the real problem to solve.

Comment: @egreg My question has been updated. ;-)

Comment: @Ingmar Thanks. That's it! Is it in the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,italian,swedish,english]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\langcase}{O{}m}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \languagename } { #2 } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

English:
\langcase[??Unsupported??]{
  {english}{start}
  {french}{début}
  {italian}{inizio}
}

\selectlanguage{french}

Français:
\langcase[??Unsupported??]{
  {english}{start}
  {french}{début}
  {italian}{inizio}
}

\selectlanguage{italian}

Italiano:
\langcase[??Unsupported??]{
  {english}{start}
  {french}{début}
  {italian}{inizio}
}

\selectlanguage{swedish}

Svenska:
\langcase[??Unsupported??]{
  {english}{start}
  {french}{début}
  {italian}{inizio}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I have just missed `\languagename`... For the switch case, I already know how to use it. I am improving my skillness(?) with LaTeX3.